# GAE Big Query - Masks when using Dates

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert a date type column into a nice human readable string like so: 25/11/2016  (or any other masks I'd like to use)

Does Big Query supports masks when using dates? When I use the Date() Functions it returns something like "2016-05-05" but that's not the standard pattern in many countries.

I've searched for a lot of different things the closes thing I got is this doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference but I didn't see anythin that would help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [STRFTIME_UTC_USEC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#strftime_utc_usec)

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(CURRENT_DATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')
```